# How to install PIL for python in Visual Studio (2012)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012

I want to import some immages to python application in my Visual Studio, but PIL must be installed first and I dont see any install software for PIL for Visual Studio.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Most folks use [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.0) nowadays. Like `PIL` you install it for the version of _Python_ you're using, not IDE. Afterwards, you'll be able to `import` it and its submodules in the Python code you execute with the Python interpreter. If you really want you should be able to download and install `PIL` from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm).

Comment: yes, but when I install it, I have this error...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9plswkfeois30c4/33.png

I have Python version 3.3.4 
x64bit on Windows 8.1

Comment: Only `pillow` supports Python 3.x -- `PIL` doesn't and isn't really being worked upon any longer -- hence why many use the latter instead. It's mostly a drop-in replacement since it's fork, is actively maintained, more bug-free (IMHO), and has a few expanded capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know PIL has not been release for Python 3.3.4 that is yet to be released. You can use PIL for Python 2.7